# How to fix 'Relay Access Denied'

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server

I'm trying to setup postfix as MTA on a AWS EC2 instance.
I want to use this as mailserver for my domains and want to use it along with Outlook/Thunderbird.

I've never setup postfix before, therefore I used this great guide here:

http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/

Now I can connect to the server via STARTTLS to mail.mydomain.com and send emails to my own email account admin@mydomain.com via Thunderbird.

However when I try to send an email to an external domain myemail@gmail.com I get an error `Relay access denied.`

The logs show:

```
May 31 14:55:58 ip-172-31-23-97 postfix/smtpd[13500]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from myhostname[97.192.4.67]: 554 5.7.1 <myemail@gmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<admin@mydomain.com> to=<myemail@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<[192.168.178.64]>
```

My postfix config:

http://pastebin.com/0jytH4Yi

I know there are many pages out there that address this issue.

Mainly the issue can be fixed by `adjusting mynetworks`, `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` or `smtpd_relay_restrictions` but none of the changes fixed my issue.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is here

```
#mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8
```

Try to add and network 192.168.178.0/24 and del #

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.178.0/24
```

Comment: Unfortunately after uncommenting the line and adding your suggestion I'm still getting the error

Comment: Is this your LAN 192.168.178.0/24?

Comment: Edit: Yes, that's the LAN IP of my windows PC from where I try to connect. How can the LAN IP be related to this?

Comment: When I insert the internet IP address of my connection to that value, it sends the email without problems: `mynetworks = 168.100.189.0/28, 127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.178.0/24, 172.31.23.0/24, xxx.193.4.67` but I don't want to manually insert the IP addresses of all clients I want to use to connect.

Comment: This is another issue :). and your solution is SASL http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html

Answer (score 0):

`smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes` is required. (not smtp_sasl_auth_enable)

Perhaps, it may be necessary to change the order of smtpd_recipient_restrictions.

`smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, (other reject rules)`

Comment: Are you sure? I don't have sasl installed on the machine and `smtp_sasl_auth_enable` is only used for the smtp connection for amazon's ses smtp server.